# Is there a program that reorganizes .cc method definitions to be ordered according to .h declarations?

Tags: c++, scripting

Is there a program that reorganizes .cc method definitions to be ordered according to .h declarations?

Comment: Time for some hacking with the clang libraries xD

Comment: Is there a need to have the method definitions is a given order?  I don't seen any reason, except for extreme optimization and my own neurotic need to have them alphabetized.

Comment: I have them grouped together in the header, and it makes it easier for me to find them if they follow the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing that I'm aware of is [Lazy C++](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/). It'll generate .h and .cc files from a single .lzz file.